# Where can you download the Cocoa & Cocoa Touch headers on Windows?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm looking for the Cocoa and Cocoa Touch header files, but I can't seem to find them anywhere online. I'm currently on a Windows computer, so I can't just pull them off of my hard drive.

I know GNUStep has header files for Cocoa (or at least header files fairly close), but I can't seem to find any for Cocoa Touch.

I have also found https://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/source/browse/branches/include-1.2-sdk/include/UIKit/UIKit.h?r=266, but it's from 2007 (and I assume they've been updated since then).

I've considered downloading/extracting the iPhone SDK/XCode and looking for them, but I'd rather not go through that much trouble if someone else has already provided them. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/MP0w/iOS-Headers

Comment: i think this question should be on programmers.stackexchange.com not stack overflow.

Comment: I think I need to go back to Googling class, thanks :\

Seeing as Bryan answered it, should I close the question here and reopen it there, or just close it?